# Add a z3 constraint, such that the value of a z3 variable equals to the return value of some function

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have a Python function that takes a real number and returns a string, e.g.

```py
def fun(x):
    if x == 0.5:
        return "Hello"
    else:
        return "Bye"
```

I start a z3 solver:

```py
from z3 import *

r = Real('r')
s = Solver()
```

Now I want to tell the solver `find a value of r, such that fun(r) returns "Hello"`. I am facing the following problems:

1. If `r = Real('r')`, then I cannot call `fun(r)`, because  `r` is a z3 variable
2. I cannot say `s.add(StringVal("Hello") == StringVal(fun(r)))` as a constraint, because 1) `r` is a z3 variable, 2) the interpretation of `r` is not known yet. Hence, I have no model from which I could extract a value and pass it to the `fun`.

Is it possible to implement what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no out-of-the box way to do this in z3, unless you're willing to modify the definition of `fun` so z3 can understand it. Like this:

```py
from z3 import *

def fun(x):
    return If(x == 0.5, StringVal("Hello"), StringVal("Bye"))

r = Real('r')
s = Solver()

s.add(fun(r) == StringVal("Hello"))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[r = 1/2]
```

So, we changed the function `fun` to use the z3 idioms that correspond to what you wanted to write. A few points:

- Obviously, not every Python construct will be easy to translate in this way. While you can express most every construct, the complexity of the hand-transformation will get higher as you work on more complicated functions.
- So far as I know, there's no automatic way to do this translation for you. However, take a look at this [blog post](https://secretlab.institute/2019/08/09/symbolic-analysis-with-python-and-z3/) for some ideas on how to do so via the disassembler.
- [PyExZ3](https://github.com/thomasjball/PyExZ3) is a now-defunct symbolic simulator for Python, using z3 as the backend solver. While the project is no longer active, you might be able to resurrect the source-code or get some ideas from it.
- You have used `Real` to model the parameter `x`. Z3's `Real` values are true mathematical reals. (Strictly speaking, they are algebraic reals, but that's besides the point for now.) Python, however, doesn't have those; instead it uses double-precision floats. But luckily, z3 understands floats, so for a more realistic encoding use the `Float64` sort. See [here](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a220d7f3190bcaaede2a579f38fdbff99) for details.

Comment: thank you for the great answer and links! I mark the question as solved because it solves it :) However, in my local case the situation is a bit more complicated, as the input of the Python function is passed further to a JS function, which does the work. It is going to be very complicated, if I try to translate all of this into z3 :) However, I have learned something new :) Thank you!

Comment: Indeed that's going to be really tricky, as you'll also have to figure out a way to "model" everything that JS does. None of this will be easy in general, but I think is quite doable if you have only a few such functions to worry about. Unfortunately, none of this is automated, so you'll have to do it manually; at least for the time being.